# How to call Template file in my controller?

Tags: php, magento

I am working in magento. I need to add a import some data using csv file. I have created a module in backend using this url.
    http://inchoo.net/magento/getting-started-with-building-admin-module-in-magento/

Currently i am getting balnk page when i click on Menu Item 1.Now i need to create a form file to add import button and submit button. when user click on submit button then save action will be fired. How i can add my template file on empty page? Please help.

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <ActiveCodeline_SampleModule1>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </ActiveCodeline_SampleModule1>
    </modules>


<global>
        <helpers>
            <SampleModule1>
                <class>ActiveCodeline_SampleModule1_Helper</class>
            </SampleModule1>  
        </helpers>
</global>        


        <admin>
        <routers>
            <samplemodule1>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>ActiveCodeline_SampleModule1</module>
                    <frontName>samplemodule1</frontName>
                </args>
            </samplemodule1>
        </routers>
    </admin>



    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <menu1 translate="title" module="SampleModule1">
                <title>ActiveCodeline SampleModule1</title>
                <sort_order>60</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <menuitem1 module="SampleModule1">
                        <title>Menu item 1</title>
                        <action>samplemodule1/example</action>
                    </menuitem1>
                </children>                
            </menu1>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <menu1 translate="title" module="SampleModule1">
                            <title>ActiveCodeline SampleModule1</title>
                            <sort_order>60</sort_order>
                            <children>
                                <menuitem1>
                                    <title>Menu item 1</title>
                                </menuitem1>
                            </children>
                       </menu1>
                   </children>
               </admin>
           </resources>
        </acl>
      <layout>
            <updates>
                <itoris_dynamicproductoptions>
                    <file>activecodeline_samplemodule1.xml</file>
                </itoris_dynamicproductoptions>
            </updates>
        </layout>


    </adminhtml>    





</config>
```

Layout / activecodeline_samplemodule1.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
    </default>
    <samplemodule1_example_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="samplemodule1" template="activecodeline/samplemodule1/custom_import.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </samplemodule1_example_index>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need add you layout update in config.xml

```
       <layout>
            <updates>
                <mymodule>
                    <file>mymodule.xml</file>
                </mymodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
```

after you need add you file layout, for example `mymodule.xml` to you package/theme in admin design namespace, directory `layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout>
      <modules_controller_action>
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="core/template" template="mymodule/template.phtml" />
            </reference>
        </modules_controller_action>
    </layout>
```

where `modules_controller_action` path to you action, `mymodule/template.phtml` path to you template.
change you layout

```
<layout>
    <updates>
        <samplemodul1>
            <file>activecodeline_samplemodule1.xml</file>
        </samplemodul1>
    </updates>
</layout>
```

in your config.xml because you use over module namespaces

Comment: where i need to create my module folder and this layout xml file?

Comment: I have created samplemodule1.xml in my layout folderand create a folder in templates named "samplemodule1". In this folder create a file custom_form.phtml. But it is showing blank page in admin.

Comment: Show you code layout samplemodule1.xml and config.xml in module, in you question.

Comment: your action `samplemodule1/example` in layout file replace this `samplemodule1_index_index` to `samplemodule1_example_index`

Comment: I have changed this still it is showing blank page. :(

Comment: I have created my phtml file folder in  /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template  named " activecodeline/samplemodule1/custom_import.phtml" and layout file in  /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout  named "activecodeline_samplemodule1.xml".

Comment: @php_dev I update answer, please look my answer again

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working fine. There was some mistake in my config.xml.

Comment: if you chouse this key `samplemodule1` for module you need use in anywhere `<helpers><your_key><your_key></helpers>`,`<models>`,'blocs' in common anywhere. Your welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This the code in your config.xml

```html
 <layout>
            <updates>
                <itoris_dynamicproductoptions>
                    <file>activecodeline_samplemodule1.xml</file>
                </itoris_dynamicproductoptions>
            </updates>
        </layout>
```

So you need to create a layout file under

```html
app/design/adminhtml/frontend/default/layout/activecodeline_samplemodule1.xml
```

For template file if you are planing to create adminhtml template then 
app/design/adminhtml/frontend/default/template/NAMEOFYOURMODULE/templatefile.phtml

Let me know if you have any query or doubts

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Please check below two controller function. where init layout will render breadcrumbs and layout.xml .

```
protected function _initAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock("content")->setTitle($this->__("Page title"));
        $breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock("breadcrumbs");
        $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("home", array(
        "label" => $this->__("Home Page"),
        "title" => $this->__("Home Page"),
        "link"  => Mage::getBaseUrl()
           ));
        $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("custommodule", array(
        "label" => $this->__("Custom Module"),
        "title" => $this->__("Custom Module")
           ));
            return $this;
  }
      public function indexAction() 
       {

                     $this->_initAction();
                     $this->renderLayout();
        }
```

Comment: there should be no logic what so ever in controllers, you should specify an observer and modify the layout by events